# Link winmm.lib to CLion using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to play music in my C++ project, but I'm getting undefined reference error. I know it was already answered here, but that doesn't help me at all:

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

I know how to fix it in VisualStudio, by adding a reference to winmm.lib to my linker. Is there a way how to do it in CLion? I tried adding it to my CMake list, but it still doesn't work, because I don't really know how to do that.

```
# Path to WinMM.Lib
link_directories(C:\\Program Files \(x86\)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.18362.0\\um\\x64)

# Link to GLFW, GLEW and OpenGL
target_link_libraries(template PUBLIC
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        ${winMM.Lib})
```

Comment: `winMM.Lib` isn't a CMake variable, so don't enclose it in curly braces.

Comment: Thank you, I never used CMake so I didn't know that. It actually helped and I'm no longer getting an error. It still can't play music, but at least I heard an error sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @arrowd said, winMM isn't a variable,so CMake file should look like this.

```
# Link to GLFW, GLEW and OpenGL
target_link_libraries(template PUBLIC
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        winMM.Lib)
```